# Android Material Palette transparency error

Tags: android, material-design, android-palette

I have recently been playing with Bitmaps and palettes when I encountered the following:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: background can not be translucent
    at android.support.v7.graphics.ColorUtils.findMinimumAlpha(ColorUtils.java:90)
    at android.support.v7.graphics.ColorUtils.getTextColorForBackground(ColorUtils.java:127)
    at android.support.v7.graphics.Palette$Swatch.ensureTextColorsGenerated(Palette.java:621)
    at android.support.v7.graphics.Palette$Swatch.getTitleTextColor(Palette.java:605)
```

Diving into the source code, I found:

```
private static int findMinimumAlpha(int foreground, int background, double minContrastRatio) {
    if (Color.alpha(background) != 255) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("background can not be translucent");
    }
    ...
}
```

The image I was using is this:

[image: a simple actionbar search icon] [image: original icon]

I think the problem has to do with how this image is entirely transparent to some degree.  I am currently implementing a nearly identical check as the throw clause `Color.alpha(palette.getSomeColor()) != 255`, but this just *feels wrong*.

Is there a method when dealing with Palettes that solves this problem for me? I feel as though it would be a common enough error that I must be doing something wrong, or missed some guide about this.

Comment: May I ask why would you want to sample color from a glyph? Usually you want to force the glyph to have a certain color not the other way around.

Comment: Just trying to handle possible user input